# Reactive.jl fps which only runs for N frames

Tags: julia

The `fps` function in Reactive.jl allows for creating a signal that activates at the given frequency.

Is it possible to create something similar, but which terminates after a given duration or number of activations?

Comment: Consider basing your implementation off the implementation of [`fpswhen`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Reactive.jl/blob/master/src/time.jl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fengyang is right. You can do this with `fpswhen`

```
switch = Signal(true)
@async (sleep(10); push!(switch, false))
ticks = fpswhen(switch, 60)
```

Here `ticks` will update at 60 fps for 10 seconds.